# Error relation "table_name" does not exist, trying to map a model @Table(name = "\"tableName\"") data class tableName()

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

I need to connect to a table named tableName, but I keep getting an error while trying to make a get request.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "table_name" does not exist
```

I'm using postgresql, and changing the name of the table in my DB to "table_name" is not an option :(

The model I have is this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"tableName\"")
data class tableName(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        var id:Long = 0,

        @Column(name = "aseg")
        var aseg:String = "",

        @Column(name = "\"expir\"")
        var expir: Date? = null,
)
```

And this is the repository:

```
   @Repository
    interface tableNameRepository: JpaRepository<tableName, Long> {
}
```

And this is the configuration I have in the properties file, also I have the configuration for the username, url and password in my file.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Comment: `table_name` and `tableName` is not the same. So what is the real and correct one? Using UPPER case in your names, is (at least in PostgreSQL) a recipe for problems. Try to avoid them. And if you really really have to, use double quotes " around the names. Always.

Comment: The correct one is tableName, and I have the double quotes. I don't think that I can change the name of the table in the db because it's used as it is on other projects.

Comment: does it table exist in database ? also please share the `application.properties` file

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you use a different name. And it’s not in this piece of code

Comment: Ensure that the table is in the correct schema if your database uses schemas. If it's in a schema, you need to include the schema name in your JPA annotations.
@Table(name = "schemaName.tableName")

Comment: This property was the solution: `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`